ResidesOutsideOfPackages but for classes in arch unit tests
 val rule: ArchRule =
     noClasses().that().resideInAPackage("$Base.app..")
             .should().dependOnClassesThat().resideOutsideOfPackages(allowablePackages)

 rule.check(importedClasses)

Hi all, I wanted to ask is there a way that I can use a similar method to resideOutsOfPackages but for a specific class instead of a package?
I want to allow an exception for ServiceA to be added to my 'allowablePackages' but I don't want the whole package where ServiceA resides to be included.
Obvious solution is to create a new package and move ServiceA to there but I was wondering was there a better solution than that?

You can combine predefined DescribedPredicates (and syntatic sugar methods for a nicer description)
import com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate.doNot
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClass.Predicates.resideOutsideOfPackages
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.properties.HasName.Predicates.name
import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.conditions.ArchPredicates.have
import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.noClasses

in the following way to allow dependencies on ServiceA even though it is not within allowablePackages:
    var rule: ArchRule = noClasses()
        .that().resideInAPackage("$Base.app..")
        .should().dependOnClassesThat(
            resideOutsideOfPackages(allowablePackages)
                .and(doNot(have(name(ServiceA::class.java.name))))
        )

